# Java- JPanel design problems

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

**UPDATE:** NVM IM AN IDIOT PASSING A NULL

ummm so I recently learned about panels and I'm trying to redesign the start menu of a tictactoe project, nothing major. 

This is my dream:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
public static void modeGUI () {

    //MAIN JFRAME GUI
    JFrame gui = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setSize(600, 200);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //MAIN PANEL
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    gui.add(mainPanel);

    //QUESTION PANEL
    JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel();
    questionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel q1 = new JLabel("Please select your mode");
    q1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    questionPanel.add(q1);
    mainPanel.add(questionPanel);

    //MODE PANEL
    JPanel  modePanel = new JPanel();
    modePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    JButton[] modeButtons = new JButton[3];
    modeButtons[0].setText("First turn");
    modeButtons[1].setText("Second turn");
    modeButtons[2].setText("P vs. P");
    for (JButton modeButton : modeButtons) {
        modeButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        modeButton.addActionListener(new Response());
        modePanel.add(modeButton);
    }
    mainPanel.add(modePanel);

    //OPTION PANEL
    JPanel optionsPanel = new JPanel();
    optionsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainPanel.add(optionsPanel);
}
```

However when I attempt to run it it gives an error at line 30, which correlates to this line: `modeButtons[0].setText("First turn");`. Can anyone help see what's wrong?

This is the error btw:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Ttt.modeGUI(Ttt.java:30)  at Ttt.main(Ttt.java:7)

Comment: _However when I attempt to run it it gives an error at line 30_ Which error? Please, post the full stack trace, it helps a lot

Comment: @BackSlash sorry and thanks for the suggestion this is it here: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Ttt.modeGUI(Ttt.java:30)
 at Ttt.main(Ttt.java:7)

Answer (score 1):

The array of buttons is empty.

```
JButton[] modeButtons = new JButton[3];
```

This line creates an array of JButtons, but each element is by default set to null (as with the creation of all arrays).

So when you try this

```
modeButtons[0].setText("First turn");
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown since `modeButtons[0]` is `null`. You have to explicitly define each button before you can begin assigning their values.